# Issue sending multipart/form-data

Tags: python, http, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm attempting to utilize BIMTrack's REST API to post an image. To do this the API requires me to send a json file with but prior to the image, inherently requiring multipart/form-data.

Failure post the json fill will be met with the error code: `415` and error message: `The content-type of the first file of the request must be application\json`.

I've successfully made this post request using the web debugging proxies of Postman & Fiddler but am unable to repeat my successes within python requests.

**Python Code** (This doesn't work) :

```
image = r"C:\Users\aflemming\Desktop\Images\DBMICon.png"
jsonFile = r"C:\Users\aflemming\source\repos\IfcOpenShell\IfcOpenShell\BIM\myjson.json"

headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer <MyToken>'}

files = {
    'Json': (None, open(jsonFile, 'rb'), 'application/json'),
    'Image': (None, open(image, 'rb'), 'image/png')
}

r = requests.post(https://api.bimtrackapp.co/v3/hubs/07La7cOZ/projects/20767/issues/3161484/viewpoints, files=files, headers=headers)
```

**Fiddler Raw Request** (This works) :

```
User-Agent:Fiddler Everywhere
Authorization:Bearer eb5e3983a7546dad76067418ff93175ef42b816dd57f78f54101f0b63862542e
Host:api.bimtrackapp.co
Content-Length:11322
Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468

---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description" 
the_text_is_here
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsonfile"; filename="myjson.json"
Content-Type: application/json

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\aflemming\source\repos\IfcOpenShell\IfcOpenShell\BIM\myjson.json*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="DBMICon.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\aflemming\Desktop\Images\DBMICon.png*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

**Postman Request** (This also works):
[image]

[image]

BIMTrack's REST API: https://api.bimtrackapp.co/swagger/ui/index

I'm happy to provide more information where required.

Comment: try getting the code directly from postman using code button below send and selecting python requests. this might help

Comment: Thanks Yash, I'd tried this previously to no avail. However after attempting it again with some new knowledge It now works! Horary! Thanks for reminding me to give it another shot.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by altering the request method (using requests.request over requests.post) and setting the `verify=False` parameter.

It seems as though the request was encountering an `SSLCertVerificationError` and bypassing the certificate resolved this.

**Final Code:**

```
image = r"C:\Users\aflemming\Desktop\Images\DBMICon.png"
jsonFile = r"C:\Users\aflemming\source\repos\IfcOpenShell\IfcOpenShell\BIM\myjson.json"
url = "https://api.bimtrackapp.co/v3/hubs/07La7cOZ/projects/20767/issues/3161484/viewpoints"

files = [
    ('Json', ('Json2', open(jsonFile,'rb'), 'application/json')),
    ('Image', ('Image2', open(image,'rb'), 'image/png'))
]

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <MyToken>'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, files = files, verify=False)
```